# Does JVM memory overhead scale linearly, or is it constant?

Tags: java, scala, clojure, jvm

In my experience, a C program that uses around 10 megabytes of resident memory may use around 40 to 50 MB when translated into Java, and around 100 in Clojure or Scala. My question is whether this JVM memory overhead scales linearly; if the C version used 1 gigabyte, would the Java version require 4 GB? Or is the JVM memory overhead more a constant factor, such that the 1 GB C program might only use 1.5 GB in Java?

I'm aware that I could benchmark this, but I think hearing people's experience regarding JVM memory use in production would be more informative than an artificial benchmark, which could be skewed to favour either result depending on how it was designed.

Comment: I would think with the excellent Garbage Collection java should show less memory utilization for similar algorithms. But this is hugely dependent in the exact program you are running

Comment: Downvoted as hugely opinion based

Comment: @om-nom-nom Then could you recommend a forum where I can solicit the opinions of people familiar with the issue?

Comment: @LogicChains although it is not a forum (just like [SO it's Q&A site](http://stackoverflow.com/about)) Quora might be a better fit.

Comment: I have 24Gb on my machine, plenty to spare, but I need to serve tens of thousands of visitors to my site - so the speed of allocation *is* important to me.  Why should I care about the exact heap size?

Comment: @KevinWright You shouldn't. But if you were writing for instance a memory-intensive video game or image/video processing program, for clients with 4gb or even less (in the case of many mobile devices), a 100% overhead can be the difference between the program running and having to cut features to reduce the memory footprint.

Comment: @LogicChains If you've run into that exact situation using Java, then you'll get a better quality of reply here by asking about your *specific* requirement.  There are too many variables involved to give a good general answer.

Comment: Seriously mods? *No way* this is opinion based. It is 100% measurable. Just because it's complex doesn't make it opinion-based. A good answer could easily highlight the key variables (implementation differences, class overhead, different data types etc.). Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overhead is about 10MB + 4xC-memory.

The 10MB is the JVM without anything. Java 7 64bit version uses about this much.

The 4x memory is obviously a "guesstimate" because it depends on which data types you use. If you use 100% references in java they take up about 4 times as much memory. The same difference there is between int and Integer.

If there are a lot of malloc/new in your C code there will be that in Java too, and Java's GC might not run when you want it to, so there's also an overhead of "dead references not yet cleaned up" that depends greatly on things out of your control (GC timing).

Comment: I guess this proves om-nom-nom's point.

Comment: malloc on the JVM is just bumping the heap pointer, "lots of malloc" is one of the main scenarios where Java performance easily out-paces C++.  You'll also find the GC to be highly tunable.

Comment: `4x` might be true if you replace C `int`s with Java `Integer`s, but that isn't a like-for-like comparison (nor is it how you would typically translate code). A C 32-bit `int` and primitive Java `int` use the same amount of space.